# Why do I get product details ONLY from the first web page instead of all the 25pages

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have a python script I divided into different functions. My first function 'get_url' is supposed to get the product url after the user have inputted the required product name in the prompt. I want to get the product details in all the pages of the site. Now when i run my code, I get product details ONLY from the first web page instead of all the 25pages. please help @Nathan Mills

HERE'S MY CODE BLOCK

```
from selenium import webdriver

import time

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

import pandas as pd


def get_url(product):
    for x in range(1, 26):
        product = product.replace(' ', '%20')
        template = 'https://www.konga.com/search?search=={product}&page=={x}'
        url = template.format(product, x)
        return url


def get_all_products(nest):
    name = nest.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'af885_1iPzH').text.strip()
    current_price = nest.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'd7c0f_sJAqi').text.strip()
    reviews = nest.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'eea9b_1Ma8-').text.strip()
    product_info = (name, current_price, reviews)
    return product_info


def main(product):
    product_list = []
    url = get_url(product)

    service = Service(executable_path="C:/driver/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
    driver.get(url)
    driver.maximize_window()
    time.sleep(5)

    product_cards = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'bbe45_3oExY')
    time.sleep(5)

    for everyCard in product_cards:
        productDetails = get_all_products(everyCard)
        product_list.append(productDetails)

    col = ['Product_Name', 'Current_Price', 'Product_Reviews']
    df = pd.DataFrame(product_list, columns=col)
    df.to_csv("C:\\Users\LP\Documents\MainTest\MainTest.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8', mode='a')


product = input('Enter Product You Are Looking For : ')

main(product)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `get_url()` has a loop that ends with return. So the function stops working after the first cycle. It generates one URL, returns it and that's all it does.
To fix that you can collect all urls into a variable inside the function and return it or change `return` to `yield`. This yield will turn your function into a generator and you can use it as a list.
Also I changed the line `url = template.format(product, x)` to `url = template.format(product=product, x=x)` as it was not working.
So the code with `yield` is the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver

import time

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

import pandas as pd


def get_url(product):
    for x in range(1, 26):
        product = product.replace(' ', '%20')
        template = 'https://www.konga.com/search?search={product}&page={x}'
        url = template.format(product=product, x=x)
        yield url


def get_all_products(nest):
    name = nest.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'af885_1iPzH').text.strip()
    current_price = nest.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'd7c0f_sJAqi').text.strip()
    reviews = nest.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'eea9b_1Ma8-').text.strip()
    product_info = (name, current_price, reviews)
    return product_info


def main(product):
    product_list = []
    url = get_url(product)

    for one_url in url:
        service = Service(executable_path="C:/driver/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
        driver.get(one_url)
        driver.maximize_window()
        time.sleep(5)

        product_cards = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'bbe45_3oExY')
        time.sleep(5)

        for everyCard in product_cards:
            productDetails = get_all_products(everyCard)
            product_list.append(productDetails)

        col = ['Product_Name', 'Current_Price', 'Product_Reviews']
        df = pd.DataFrame(product_list, columns=col)
        df.to_csv("C:\\Users\LP\Documents\MainTest\MainTest.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8', mode='a')
        driver.quit()


product = input('Enter Product You Are Looking For : ')

main(product)
```

Comment: Hi @Eugene Okulik, thanks for your response. Unfortunately  I still got same result with "yield url". Any other fix to this ?

Comment: You also need to replace `template = 'https://www.konga.com/search?search=={product}&page=={x}'` by `template = 'https://www.konga.com/search?search={product}&page={x}'`. Site doesn't understand this additional "=" sign. And when it receives "==2" it tries to find the page "=2", but it only has a page "2". So it fails to find the requested page and always shows the first page.

Comment: Hi Eugeny I did all you instructed and still getting same result- only data from first page is scraped. When I use "yield url" the page doesn't load at all but when i use return url, it loads but still returning same result.

Comment: Did you create a `for` loop for going through the urls? Have you tried to copy my code and run it (I've just updated it with correct `templates`)?

Comment: Thank you @Eugeny, the for loop worked. I'm grateful for your help

Comment: Ofcourse my friend, you're a genius. Your answered. I'm super grateful